# Esc in GridViewDateTimeColumn inside radDataGridView after I did an e.Cancel = true in Row Validation

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a problem and had been searching the web and couldn't find anything that will help me.

this is my problem.
Im working in WinForm , c#

I have a grid where is a Column of type **GridViewDateTimeColumn**.
When the user update a row I check it in the event **RowValidating** and if I get a repeated date or other error I show the user a message and I do **e.cancel = true** to not validate the row.
But then If I press ESC. I cannot cancel all the changes like it usually does before 
Any idea how to do it?

Here is my code:

```
 private void grdPirteyMenahel_RowValidating(object sender, RowValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            if (e.Row != null)
            {

             //Generate a service to connect to DB                  
               var factory = new MezumanimChannelFactory<IKerenService>(ServiceConsts.SERVICE_KEREN);
               var service = factory.CreateChannel();
               string sError = string.Empty;
               //here I call a SP in the database that check if the dates are correct (column of dates are call it "MiTaarich" and "AdTaarich".
               //The SP return a String with the error, if there is no error it will return and empty string

               sError = GetErrorPirteySacharMenahel(Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells["MiTaarich"].Value), Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells["AdTaarich"].Value), Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells["Kod"].Value));

                            if (sError != string.Empty)
                            {
                                e.Cancel = true;
                                RadMessageBoxHelper.Alert(sError);
                            }
               }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Elad.Mezumanim.Client.Utils.Log.LogUtil.write(ex);
            e.Cancel = true;
            RadMessageBoxHelper.Alert(Messages.DataDisplayError, this);
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
```

I also tried adding this code when i get the error:

```
 DataTable dt = (grdPirteyMenahel.DataSource as DataTable);
  dt.RejectChanges();
```

But this recover the value of date as it was before (what is good) but doesn't let me get out of the row when I press ESC

Any idea how to solve it?

thank you very much
best regards
Iair

Comment: Does your `Grid` have a method called `CancelEdit()`? The standard `DataGridView` has such a method and can cancel the current edit easily.

Comment: Thanks King King but didnt work, I tried adding grdPirteyMenahel.CancelEdit() before and after I do the e.cancel and didnt work.
neither worked when I did the cancelEdit() without doing the e.cancel = true.
In that case it added me the row anyway with the invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I asked Telerik about it, and theY gave me a solution.
its not a real solution its more like a patch a workaround but for the moment its good for me.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/esc-in-gridviewdatetimecolumn-inside-raddatagridview-after-i-did-an-e-cancel-true-in-row-validation.aspx

thanks
Iair